# How do I get the page tags a widget belongs to?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've created a Page-Redirect Widget. 
But I've the problem that I can't change the page if the redirect widget is added. 
It redirects ;-)

So I can't deactivate the redirect or change the destination.

As global switch I've added a widget load option, but it would be cool to set a tag in the page settings to enable/disable the redirect.

Is there a way to get this information? 
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the `data.page.tags` array to the widget's options object

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'redirectsData', 'redirectsWidget', {
   pageTags: data.pages.tags
}) }}
```

Then you could check `data.options.pageTags` in your widget template to do or not do a thing.

Comment: The redirect is currently done in ```self.load```. I haven't found a way to get the options from page there. Is it possible? But I've a new idea now to get it to work in the template with a helper, maybe... will see tomorrow.

Comment: Got stuck. First `data.options.pageTags` is not needed because this would be the same as `data.page.tags`. I could use it for a `data.options.enabled`.  But my problem is here, that in the scopes where the page and widget data is available I can not set the Location header. If I can set the Location header the data is not available. At least I don't know where. I've put two gists up: [index.js](https://gist.github.com/kolbma/3f7c82ec735fffbc5efb8bfa6bc8421e), [widget.html](https://gist.github.com/kolbma/c9cdc1bb95daa3083cdf10706d45bc2b)

Comment: Ah, misunderstood where you were. In your `load` function you have access to `req` which will let you peek at `req.data.user` where you can look at what permissions group a user has, which could be a useful thing to make a decision about whether or not to auto redirect a user or let them pause on the current page.

Comment: Ah. Great. That's a good idea. No tags. Just the edit-permission. Works.

Comment: Please accept the answer so stackoverflow knows it is correct. Thanks.